# Android: Listview where each item is a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a listview with a custom adapter for each item of the list. If my custom item is some textview everything works fine. But each item has to be some html and hence I need each item to be a webview. The problem is that the webview steals my click and thus I cannot select an item from the list anymore.

So this:

```
    this.itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.webview, itemArrayList);
    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener( new ItemSelected());
    lv1.setAdapter(this.itemAdapter);

public class ItemSelected implements OnItemClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int item, long id) 
    {
        Intent showTextIntent = new Intent(showItems, ShowItemDetails.class); 
        showTextIntent.putExtra("itemID", singleItems.get(item).getItemID());
        startActivity(showTextIntent);
    }
}
```

click is dead. I don't have any link in the webview or have to navigate I only use it to have a nice formatted text (fromHtml for the textview is not that nice). Any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do [`setClickable(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) in your `WebView`, or use [`android:clickable="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable) on the XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

I've found two ways to achieve it:

**1: Set a touch listener on the WebView to redirect the touch event**

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Do your thing
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**2: Avoid all possible touch events from being fired**

```
webView.setClickable(false);
webView.setLongClickable(false);
webView.setFocusable(false);
webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the webviews attributes clickable and focusable to false worked for me.
Doing that ListView's OnItemClickListener was firing again.